# Dynamic CSS using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, css

I want to set the window width (getting by JavaScript) in a PHP variable and use it to describe the attribute of the div container, but the following code doesn't work...

```html
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); // Parsing CSS zu PHP
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    if(typeof(window.innerWidth) !== 'number') {
        if(document.documentElement.clientWidth !== 0) {
            width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            height = document.documentElement.clientHeight; 
        }
        else {
            width  = document.body.clientWidth;
            height = document.body.clientHeight;
        }
    }else {
        width  = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
    }
    $cwidth = document.write(width);
    </script>";
?>
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
#container
{
    width: <?php echo $cwidth . 'px'; ?>; 
}
```

Greets

Comment: PHP (server) is processed before JavaScript (client).

Comment: You're confusing technologies. JavaScript cannot report anything to PHP because it happens after PHP has executed. PHP is a server-side language, so it does its thing before anything reaches the browser. JS is client-side, so it does its thing in, and once content reaches, the browser. You need to re-think your approach here. You should aim for a pure CSS solution to what you're doing (which seems to be quite simple) but if you really need scripting involved, set the CSS directly via JavaScript, on the element's `style` object - no PHP involved.

Comment: You can't assign the result of a JS calculation to a PHP variable. JS is client side, PHP is server side.

Comment: You need to use AJAX for that, but AJAX seems to be far beyond what you're able to do. As said above you need to learn the concept of client and server.

Comment: What you're asking isn't going to work the way you're trying to do it, but in any case, I would **strongly** advise against having dynamic CSS in this way. There are ways to achieve what you want to do in CSS without needing to get PHP involved. Google for phrases like *responsive design CSS* and similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to the bottom of your HTML page and the width of #container gets set by JS when the page loads:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if(typeof(window.innerWidth) !== 'number') {
    if(document.documentElement.clientWidth !== 0) {
        width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        height = document.documentElement.clientHeight; 
    }
    else {
        width  = document.body.clientWidth;
        height = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
}else {
    width  = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
}
document.getElementById('container').style.width = width;
</script>
```

btw: You wrote *clinet* instead of *client* in your JS.